# Insert into 120 columns from 120-indexed array

Tags: c#, sql, list, c#-4.0, dapper

I have column names like this

```
Id
,Test
,[H01_1]
,[H01_2]
,[H01_3]
,[H01_4]
,[H01]
,[H02_1]
,[H02_2]
,[H02_3]
,[H02_4]
,[H02]
,[H03_1]
,[H03_2]
,[H03_3]
,[H03_4]
,[H03]
,[H04_1]
,[H04_2]
,[H04_3]
,[H04_4]
,[H04]
,[H05_1]
,[H05_2]
,[H05_3]
,[H05_4]
,[H05]
,[H06_1]
,[H06_2]
,[H06_3]
,[H06_4]
,[H06]
,[H07_1]
,[H07_2]
,[H07_3]
,[H07_4]
,[H07]
,[H08_1]
,[H08_2]
,[H08_3]
,[H08_4]
,[H08]
,[H09_1]
,[H09_2]
,[H09_3]
,[H09_4]
,[H09]
,[H10_1]
,[H10_2]
,[H10_3]
,[H10_4]
,[H10]
,[H11_1]
,[H11_2]
,[H11_3]
,[H11_4]
,[H11]
,[H12_1]
,[H12_2]
,[H12_3]
,[H12_4]
,[H12]
,[H13_1]
,[H13_2]
,[H13_3]
,[H13_4]
,[H13]
,[H14_1]
,[H14_2]
,[H14_3]
,[H14_4]
,[H14]
,[H15_1]
,[H15_2]
,[H15_3]
,[H15_4]
,[H15]
,[H16_1]
,[H16_2]
,[H16_3]
,[H16_4]
,[H16]
,[H17_1]
,[H17_2]
,[H17_3]
,[H17_4]
,[H17]
,[H18_1]
,[H18_2]
,[H18_3]
,[H18_4]
,[H18]
,[H19_1]
,[H19_2]
,[H19_3]
,[H19_4]
,[H19]
,[H20_1]
,[H20_2]
,[H20_3]
,[H20_4]
,[H20]
,[H21_1]
,[H21_2]
,[H21_3]
,[H21_4]
,[H21]
,[H22_1]
,[H22_2]
,[H22_3]
,[H22_4]
,[H22]
,[H23_1]
,[H23_2]
,[H23_3]
,[H23_4]
,[H23]
,[H24_1]
,[H24_2]
,[H24_3]
,[H24_4]
,[H24]
```

And I am trying to write a simple INSERT with dapper (SQL Server 2014).
For the Id and Test I am writing an anonymous object to put into the param but I wasn't sure whats the best way to take a 120 length int? array and insert it into the columns beginning with H

Where index 0 goes to H01_1 and index 1 goes to H01_2 ... etc

I don't want to have to write SQL that says

```
H01_1 = @H01_1,
H01_2 = @H01_2,
...
```

And then also have to make an anonymous object that does

```
H01_1 = array[0],
H01_2 = array[1],
...
```

One thing I can do is insert just Id and Test and then go back and do an UPDATE on that record. But I am still in the same scenario I was before where I don't know the best way to write an UPDATE in dapper without writing things out 120 times.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is possible to change your datatable structure  then only follow below design

   In your table you have more number of column and find out that your assigned ID as primary . So instead of using above data structure use below ..

> ```
> ID                 test          column                            value
> ```
>
> > ```
> > 01               xyz           H01_1                           val_H01_1
> > ```
>
> ```
>   01               xyz             H01_2                         val_H01_2
> ```

Assign group primary key for ID,test and column..

2. If it is not possible for changing structure . Then create a XML from your front end data and create Stored procedure like below to excute it . If you go through with http://www.itworld.com/article/2960645/development/tsql-how-to-use-xml-parameters-in-stored-procedures.html then you will get idea.

Comment: I cant change the structure, and I wanted something that was more straight forward than making 120 variables in dapper. XML is a more complicated solution